# On Click of form elements in jQuery Mobile Screen Freezes

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I Have designed a page using jQuery mobile, & in the data-role="main" section I have defined the form elements, when I open the page in mobile browser and as soon as I click to fill the input section my screen gets freezes, unable to scroll down.

But in the same place if keep a long text instead of form elements it works fine for me.

Also I have kept my header and footer position fixed if I remove position fixed then all form elements work fine except the date picker.

Comment: Show your code/jsfiddle

Comment: Its working fine in chrome mobile view

Comment: Well its working fine in Iphone5 as well